# Updating a mysql datable with new records from another table 'where not exist'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two mysql tables. A live table 'tx_product' and a upload table 'tx_product_upload' with each about 500,000 records.

```
table tx_product
id|unique_id|name|

table tx_product_upload
id|unique_id|product_name|
```

I upload a new dataset each day into table tx_product_upload (first truncate, then upload). The new dataset has about 2000 new records (with new unique_ids) each day and with possible updated product_name definitions.

What I wanted to do now (1.Step) is to update the live table 'tx_product' with the new unique_ids available and relevant product_name defintions from table tx_product_upload with this query:

```
query:
INSERT INTO tx_product
(unique_id, name)
SELECT unique_id AS unique_id, product_name AS name
FROM tx_product_upload
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT unique_id, name
              FROM tx_product
              WHERE tx_product.unique_id = tx_product_upload.unique_id );
```

But when I run the query via phpMyAdmin ... the query seems to run forevever and freezes after some time. ... and both table can't be used (tested simple copy or access) if I close phpMyAdmin and open it again.

I could also run the query via ubuntu console ... but what's the best way to update table tx_product with the new records available in table tx_product_upload? I'm on a shared server. I know this might be a possible dublicate ... but I need to have a working solution for this

Comment: Try the code from this link: [Fastest Insert](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/fastest-way-to-insert-new-records-where-one-doesnt-already-exist) it even shows which way is the fastest for which amount of records

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for the link. I think I' ll next try the LEFT JOIN for my case ...